# Javascript not being parsed correctly, causing the URL to change when loaded

Tags: javascript

So I have the following code I am creating as part of the freecodecamp.com current weather project.

```
<html><head>
<!--Bootstrap CDN - 3.3.7 Complete CSS-->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--jQuery CDN - 3.2.1 Uncompressed-->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Weather by Current Location</title>

<style>
  body{
    background-color: #141b28;  //Purple
  }
  #weather-box{
    margin-top: 5%;
    color: #C0C0C0;  //Silver
  }
</style>
<script>
  //var location = [1,2];
  function getLocation(){
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 container-fluid text-center" 
    id="weather-box">
    <h1>Weather</h1>
  </div> 
</div>
</body></html>
```

The above code runs just fine, but when I uncomment`//var location = [1,2];` and reload the document, the local URL changes from `~/weatherApp/index.html` to `~/weatherApp/1,2` and fails to load.  The [1,2] is just a placeholder for testing.  Can anyone tell me why this could be happening, clearly it's grabbing the contents of that array, but I'm not sure why it would be replacing the URL?  As far as I can tell, all my tags, parens, and brackets are all correct.  This is happening in Chrome and Firefox, so it must be something with my own work.  Any help you guys could provide would be appreciated.

Comment: `location` is reserved, here is a list of javascript reserved words https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: @NewToJS — It is predefined, not reserved. Avoid w3schools. It is very often wrong.

Comment: @Quentin Fair enough. I will keep that in mind for future :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `location` global is a [predefined browser variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

You are getting the expected behaviour for assigning a value to it.

---

The quick and dirty solution to the problem is to *use a different variable name*.

---

The better solution, which avoids problems from:

- Globals you just haven't heard about before
- New browser default globals introduced in the future
- Globals from third party scripts loaded onto the page (including ones loaded by browser extensions)

… is to avoid using globals in the first place.

Wrap your code in an IIFE so your variables are locally scoped:

```
(function () {
    var location = [1,2];
    function getLocation(){
    }
})();
```

This obviously prevents you from accessing your variables as globals, but you shouldn't need to do this in all but a few obscure edge cases. You should bind event handler functions using `addEventListener` and not intrinsic event attributes (like `onclick`) so that you don't need event handler functions to be global.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you.  I'm reading about event listeners now and this should work with everything I will need to do.